# M2e is not visible in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

I'm trying to install m2e plugin to enable maven integration but it looks like plugin is not installed:

What I do:
Maven is already installed in the system and 'mvn --version' works

1. Help -> Install New Software -> Indigo->General Purpose Tools - m2e
2. Eclipse restart of course
3. There is no mention of Maven in eclipse. Not in Window->Preferences, not when creating new project. Nowhere.

Tried different plugin repositories, tried Eclipse Marketplace - nada.

When running Eclipse I get these errors:

```
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: SLF4J logger factory is not an instance of LoggerContext: org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory
2 [org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler] INFO org.mortbay.log - Logging to org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
```

Not sure what to do at this point.
Would be grateful for any help!

Leonty

Comment: I'm also having this problem with Eclipse Indigo 3.7.2 (SR2), with m2e 1.0.200. m2e just "vanished", gone, invisible, nothing. I'm trying to reinstall m2e from a clean Eclipse JEE distro. Hopefully this works, if not, I can be very mad.

Comment: FWIW - I get the SLF4F warning too, but M2E just worked for me after I followed the same install steps as you -- with the same versions Hendy mentioned.  I would carefully examine all my software sources and if nothing works, start with a clean install and a clean workspace and go from there.

Comment: What is shown in your Help/Installed Software/Already installed

Comment: I use STS which is an Eclipse distribution that comes with Spring and m2e pre-installed. Other than that it's plain vanilla Eclipse.  http://www.springsource.org/downloads/sts-ggts

Answer (score 1):

I don't recall what it is called in Indigo. I recently updated to Juno and imported my plugins with no issue. Below is a full list of plugins that I have installed. I'd recommend you uninstall what you have, then search for "Maven Integration". Install that and any other related plugins you will need (i.e. SCM clients).

[image: List of plugins for m2e]

Answer (score 0):

It is builtin with Indingo, no !?

(Or maybe Indigo WTP)

I am quite sure because I had to re-install Indigo WTP several times